$\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x+3^x)^\frac{1}{x} = 3$
How to conclude $\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x+3^x)^\frac{1}{x} = 3$ ?
I was using Desmos to get a hint to compute the limit, but I only saw that the graph has two horizontal asymptotes, which are:

$y=2$
$y=3$

And it has one vertical asymptote: $x=0$.
Now my question is: What technique or method do I have to use to see $\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x+3^x)^\frac{1}{x} = 3$ ? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

oh thanks, the link you got is exactly the same question what I got.

Hint: Use that $3^x < 2^x + 3^x < 3^x + 3^x = 2*3^x$.

If I were to compute this: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2^x+3^x)}{x}$, am I allow to use L'Hospital's Rule? And why? Because, if I plugin the infinity into the $x$, then I will get: $\frac{\ln(\infty + \infty)}{\infty}$, the concern what I am having is, the infinity plus infinity inside the ln() function. Ofcourse $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is indeterminate, but I can't just go to that conclustion right away, because I need to "compute" infinity plus infinity first.
